# Prestashop: Add products to a new cart

Tags: web-services, cordova, prestashop

This is not a general problem, but I hope someone has encountered this issue!!

I have a [prestashop](http://www.prestashop.com/en/) website, and now I'm creating a mobile version of this site, using [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/).

I connect to the site data base via the [prestashop webservice](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS14/Web-service+reference).

I can add a new cart, but this cart is empty and It doesn't belong to the customer who have added a product to his cart.

I have expected to use an url like this:

```
http://monsite/Create_carts.php?id_product=..&quantity=..&id_customer=..
```

but there is not an id_product or an id_customer attribute in the cart object.

My question is how to add products to a cart and make it belong to the logged customer?

Comment: how is your phonegap holding a session in prestashop? 
What version of prestashop are you running? 
what is your create_carts.php doing?

Comment: Did you make any progress since 5 years ago? (:

Answer (score -1):

You have an order object which links to a cart object and a customer object. There is also a cart_product object which links to a product and a cart. 
Database structure:

```
customer -> order -> cart -> cart_object.
```

That is how it is in the database, I have no idea how to use the API to do that as I'm searching for that myself...
It usually seems to be that you get a blank schema, populate it with the correct data and then send it in to add it to the database. You can get the blank schema with something like:

```
$xml = $webService->get(array('url' => 'http://my_prestashop_shop/api/carts?schema=blank'));
```

But as I have stated. I cant seem to do this myself. I will come back if I find the answer.